# How to create a transparent toolbar and status bar and overlay an image for this class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have an xml layout file called fragment_about_sl.xml and the class associated to that called aboutSLFragment.java which is extended to fragment.java. Anyway all I want to do is make the toolbar transparent and overlay the image for this class only.I am new to android, so please help.

fragment_about_sl.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/aboutslscrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

aboutSlFragment.java

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;
TextView aboutsltext;
Button readmorebtn;

public aboutSLFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, 
false);
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView .findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());

viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

    dots[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), 
R.drawable.non_active_dot));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

    sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

}

dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), 
R.drawable.active_dot));

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), 
R.drawable.non_active_dot));
        }


dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), 
R.drawable.active_dot));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});

aboutsltext=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutsltext);
readmorebtn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.readmorebtn);
readmorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (readmorebtn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Read More"))
        {
            aboutsltext.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);//your TextView
            readmorebtn.setText("Read Less");
        }
        else
        {
            aboutsltext.setMaxLines(3);//your TextView
            readmorebtn.setText("Read More");
        }
    }
});

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments 
different titles
getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}
```

**I want my app to be like this**
[image: expected result]

Comment: do you wanna collapse the toolbar upon scrolling ??

Comment: Hello santanu Sur, Yes I want the toolbar to collapse upon scrolling.Please help me, I am new to android

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Comment: Hello Santanu, please can you give me a working code, or atleast a link to a working code

Comment: try this out.. https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: Hello Santanu, Just a question, is there anything,any code to put inside the java class or is it only the  code that is in the xml file

Comment: just the xml is enough fo this

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in onResume of that fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```